# Can I use oauth2 without having ui?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, oauth, oauth-2.0

Basicly if I know the person's username and password is there a way to pass them without needing for him to enter them?
I have a webservice with no UI and want to use the Outlook REST API which uses OAuth 2.

Comment: Think about it. How would you pass the details that were entered? Instead of passing the values you'd grab from the UI, pass the details you've pulled from config instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need an UI for OAuth2? All you need is a web browser to open an url, but it is not required to open this url on the same device which runs your web service. So, you could start the authentication in your web service (triggered by your user) and then send him the link to enter his credentials via mail. After this, your callback url will give you the required access token.

One main intention behind OAuth2 is, to **NOT** give a third party any user password. Any login should only affect the user and the main application provider.

So I assume, if OAuth2 is implemented in the correct way, there is no way to register your users with username and password directly via your code.

Comment: Thank you this is what I have been looking for.The Outlook API is made that way.

Comment: this NEVER is not true in case of 'password' grant type ;)